# Sendgrid create template and version in one request

Tags: api, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to create template using [api request](https://sendgrid.com/docs/api-reference/). Response returns json which contains version as well but when i check there isn't any version. In documentation says `template_id`is required. But i can get it when template will be created.

Actually i am doing 2 request. First one to create template and second one to create version.

How can i create template and version in one request? my request looks like:

```
{
  "id": "23456789012",
  "name": "23456789012_name",
  "generation": "dynamic",
  "versions": [
      {
        "template_id": "23456789012",
        "active": 1,
        "name": "23456789012_version1",
        "html_content": "some html content",
        "plain_content": "some plain content",
        "subject": "{{subject}}",
        "editor": "design"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I think that's not possible and 2 requests are the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked to official sendgrid support. They told it is not possible. But have no idea why they posted it in documentation. So, if someone has same problem, then can check [this link](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/requests/1982437).